# How to selectively split negative symbol and subtraction operator in Java?

Tags: java, split

I'm using Java to work with a fraction calculator. It takes in two fractions input as string (e.g. `3/8 + 3/4`), splits the slashes `/` and any operators contain within `+-*/` and stores two numerators and two denominators separately into array before it proceeds with the calculation.

```
String [] fractionsplit = fractioninput.split("/|\\-");              // ("/|\\+"); ("\\*|\\/"); ("/"); for addition, multiplication and division respectively

    Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(fractionsplit[0]);
    Integer den1 = Integer.parseInt(fractionsplit[1]);
    Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(fractionsplit[2]);
    Integer den2 = Integer.parseInt(fractionsplit[3]);
```

I'm asking whether there is a way to split the symbol selectively? Because negative input (e.g. `-3/8`) the negative symbol is equivalent to subtraction operator `-`. Once `.split("/|\\-");` is executed, all the `-` will be split, negative input 'unintentionally' becomes positive input and run into error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: ""
>           at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
>           at Assignment.AdditionSubtraction.subtraction(fraction.java:86)
>           at Assignment.fraction.main(fraction.java:42)

How can I reconstruct the way I split the string input? Addition operation is the only thing worked out, subtraction, multiplication and division will run into the same error as above.

Comment: I wonder whether a more dedicated parsing approach might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use split for that. With split, you cannot use the context of a symbol. Your problem with multiple `-` signs requires the context to be solved.

A simple and elegant approach to solve this would be the use of Regular Expressions with Capture Groups. (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm)

I quickly sketched a Regex that should work for your problem (at least as I understood it):

`(\-?[\d]+)\/(\-?[\d]+)([\+\-\*\/])(\-?[\d]+)\/(\-?[\d]+)`

Here you can see it in action (on the right side, you see the extracted groups):
https://regex101.com/r/J1mI4j/2

Comment: The grouping regex is so confusing, I'll need some time to get into it. Meanwhile I have to reconstruct the whole split and parsing thing?

Comment: The regex looks complex and confusing but actually it is not. It consists of the same elements that are repeated: 
(\-?[\d]+) -> represents a group that might start with a `-`, followed by at least one numeric character or more

Comment: The middle part: ([\+\-\*\/]) represents the operator group, so it is one character of given list: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`. That are the relevant parts of the regex..